# Accessing files obscured by filesystem mounted at non-empty directory

Tags: macos, unix, mount, symbolic-link, hardlink

I wish to mount a volume/filesystem at a non-empty directory, yet still retain access to the directory's contents. Is this possible?

I know that a filesystem can be mounted at a non-empty directory with no issues -- the data will remain when the filesystem is unmounted. What I *do* want to know is how to access that data while the filesystem is mounted.

I tried creating a hard link to the directory, but even the new directory essentially becomes a second mountpoint. I could verify this by running `ls -i` and noting that the `inode` for the hard link changed to match the `inode` of the mounted volume. Is there something happening at the [VFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) layer here?

Could I potentially keep some handle on the directory open before mounting and it would remain useful? Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Search for "union mount" - I think that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is a way to do [Linux's `mount --bind`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) on OS X. You can try [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) and see if it works for you.